# Can Google Calendar Gadgets be installed automatically when installing a Google Apps Marketplace App?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-gadget

I know in the [Google Apps Marketplace SDK](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing#configure_the_google_apps_marketplace_sdk) you can specify a [Gmail Contextual Gadget](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets) in the COB Extension section however there doesn't seem to be anyway to have a [Google Apps Marketplace app](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/) install [Calendar Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/) automatically.

Barring that, is it possible for the Google Apps admin to install the Calendar Gadget for all the users on the Google Domain directly?

It doesn't seem like either of these is possible, is this correct?  If so it's really disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to install a calendar gadget is for each user to click on the install URL for the gadget.  They need to accept the gadget and then it is installed and available.

You could look to use a chrome extension instead.  Although this has its own installation challenges for a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Only applications that belong to Google Apps Marketplace (they have enabled the GAM SDK) can be installed by the administrator and make them accessible for every one in the domain.

In the case of the Gmail Contextual Gadgets, although those are gadgets, they are part of a Marketplace project and therefore can be installed across the domain.